# What happens when you hit the hard limit in Idle Oil Tycoon?

Tags: idle-oil-tycoon

I've been playing [Idle Oil Tycoon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moldygames.oiltycoon&hl=en) on Android for a while, and I am at the point where many of the upgrades are purchasable (they prices show up as "infinity" signs).

I suspect this is due to some data type overflow that happens somewhere in the region of 10^306-10^309.

While a bit interesting, and telling me a bit about the programming of the game (in some cases one can deduce in which order a certain calculation takes place, for example), I feel an impending doom knowing that I will soon hit a point where my cash balance hits the overflow limit. I'm hoping someone else has already hit this point and can answer the following question:

What happens when I reach the limit? Do I instantly get infinite experience and thus infinite income from even a single property (effectively ending the game), or is there some progression beyond this point?

(Note that this is done in Unlimited Mode and took a few months to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens:

[image]

Somewhere in the region of high 10^307's to low 10^308's, your cash balance becomes *infinity*. This also means your experience upon reset is infinity, which in turn gives you infinite money from any property after resetting, however you cannot purchase any of the infinite cost upgrades or properties.

Thus, this point is the end of all progression.

Comment: Having infinite score is infinitely better than a buffer overflow.